How to set separated rules for 80 and 443 listeners of AWS EKS's ingress object?
I want to set ingress object for EKS. Now it looks like:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:ap-northeast-1:0123456789:certificate/uuid
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: eks-lb-group
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: eks-lb-name
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "443"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: public-A,public-C,public-D
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /healthchek
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  name: ingress-name
  namespace: namespace-name
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service-name
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix

This configuration is translated into AWS ALB rules and it looks like

HTTP (80) listener is redirecting all requests to HTTPS (443) listener (controlled by alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "443")
HTTPS (443) listener is forwarding traffic to service-name related target group if hostname is example.com.

It is mostly fine, but I don't want to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS if hostname is example.com. I want to forward this traffic to service-name related target group without redirecting it to HTTPS listener.
How to add this example.com rule not only for HTTPS but also for HTTP external ALB listener?
